# Galaxy S4 back button pressing itself

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4

After replacing the digitizer, the back (and sometimes menu) button randomly presses itself. I feel the phone vibrate as if the button was actually pressed but it was not. Sometimes there are a number of presses in a quick succession.

I did a factory reset but problem remains. Everything seems to be connected OK, I even put some electric tape between the back & menu ribbon cables to prevent shorting.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Notice does this happen all the time or when you plugin something such as the charging cable, earphone etc.? And what is the frequency of this issue?

Comment: Happens all the time and fairly frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a strictly mechanical issue. If the phone is bent in any way, it can put pressure on the digitizer without any involvement from you.  If you take the phone apart again (but don't disconnect the cables), does the digitizer behave the same or was the pressure from the frame causing the issue?   This is obviously not a specific answer to your question, but answers to these questions would help you understand the next steps to take.  Issues like this are usually either a faulty digitizer or faulty (or badly installed) connectors.

Comment: That crossed my mind too. I removed the very tight rubber/silicon case, then I tried playing with the tightness of the screws - no change. I removed the bezel and it seems to be working better but it's kind of hard to tell because without the bezel the battery moves around and you can't easily test. I'll try again later tonight.

Comment: Switched the back bezel /mid frame housing and left the screws out and it seems to have helped a bit - the button still presses itself occasionally but not as often as before.