# Samsung Galaxy S6: Back button presses by itself

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-6

On my Samsung Galaxy S6 (Android 6.0.1), sometimes the back button starts firing by itself, hence closing the current app or going back on a page. Other times it's like a ghost press on other parts of the screen, so that e.g. the menu opens by itself. Often this happens in bursts, making the device unusable.

It's a common problem, as seen here:

- https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/help/s6-pressing-button-self-capacitive-key-t3146253
- https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/519860-galaxy-s6-capicitative-back-button-spamming.html
- https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/556632-back-button-issue-ghost-pressing-constantly-how-can-i-fix.html
- https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/Smartphones-Tablets-Wearables/S6-back-button-self-pressing/td-p/160823
- https://forum.xda-developers.com/s7-edge/help/random-screen-presses-button-presses-t3599821

Users report as possible causes:

1. Device overheating
2. Use of data connection (perhaps causing #1)
3. Hardware problem (interference from speakers on the capacitive touchscreen)
4. Moisture (triggering false contacts on the capacitive touchscreen)

In my case, I've noticed it happening especially when I use the Twitter app, which makes large use of the phone capabilities. Running Smart Manager and closing all running apps sometimes solves the issue, so it might really be #1.

Users suggest possible solution (none of which are working):

1. Factory reset and/or cache reset
2. Let device cool down
3. Disable data and/or WiFi connection
4. Lower volume speakers to less than 75% (?)
5. Dial *#2663# and do a TSP FW Update (General)

Anyone found a definitive fix for it?

I've had this happen to me on 2016 (hence the post), then the problem disappeared by itself, now in 2019 it's back, more annoying than ever.

Note: Related to an older Galaxy model: [Galaxy S4 back button pressing itself](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/122540/galaxy-s4-back-button-pressing-itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem. Tried everything but nothing completely solved the problem. Finally visited the service centre and had it fixed. They said some fault in the diigitizer  under the back button  which started going on  like the back button was pressed when the device hits a certain temperature.

One thing you can try : (If you are rooted) Enable the on-screen navigation buttons and disable the normal sensor buttons and see if the problem persists. Mine was just a month old so i went to the service centre.

Good Luck hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem. I did a factory reset which solved nothing, i tried the code which resets touch screen sensortivity.  No joy.  It's hardware. If your phone is under warranty take it back.  My cell was not so took it too local repair shop. They replaced a strip that runs around perimeter of my cell. This strip contains the sensors on the bottom of the cell and the side as well as the charger port.

Problem solved. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think of it as a software problem really because if you did a factory reset that should iron most kinks in the OS. And this isn't restricted to the S6 only as it had been reported as early as the S4. It had been attributed likely to a hardware problem caused either during packaging/ transportation/ mechanical damage e.g during a fall read [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/125182/145490)

If your device is fairly new take it back for repair or to an authorized Samsung repair center. In opening the phone they are likely to ease pressure on the plate that makes the the contact between the back button and the mechanical hardware component.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsuiIF8CbvA

ie *#2663# and press the button 'TSP FW Update (General)'

**UPDATE** Problem returned after 30 minutes.

Comment: Tried this too, did not work.